# Django for loop inside jQuery gives me unexpected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I saw few examples of Django's for loop inside jQuery, but when I replicate it gives me console error, like doesn't read the `{% for i...%}`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2019-05-31',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, 
    events: [  
      {% for i in sales_events %} // gives error
        { title: "i.title", }
      {% endfor %}
    ]
  });
});
```

Errors:

> Property assignment expected.
>   Expression expected.
>   ':' expected.

Comment: Firstly, where is this code being executed? If it's in a .js file then the Django logic won't be interpreted. Secondly, you need commas between the objects in your JS array.

Comment: Also you haven't specified `event` anywhere. I presume this is supposed to be in the arguments of the function

Comment: Also how is this script being included on the page?  I'm assuming for the django syntax to work, the js would have to go through a preprocessor first.

Comment: You need `{ title: "{{ i.title }}" }`. IMHO

Comment: is an .html file, the line event.preventDefault() should not be there,, there is django snipets working perfectly alongside the html above. Aswell is within <script> tags.. It should not give error the for loop? weird..

Answer (score 0):

The for loop was working all time, just the editor throw errors due not recognizing django template tags inside script tags.. amazing.. Thanks to all...

Answer (score 0):

and Added this extension to not shown errors.. Jus in case
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bibhasdn.django-html